# JS Assign the value of variable depending on conditional

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't know why this doesn't work. Any ideas?

```js
   let a = 0
    if (a == 0) {return let a = value0}
    else if (a == 1) {return let a = value1}
    else {return let a = valuex}
    console.log(a)
```

The console always says `0`. What should I do?

Comment: Put your code in a snippet.As you can see, this does not work. Please add correct code

Comment: `let` isn’t an expression. Why do you even have `return` there? What are you actually testing? Only `if(a == 0)` will ever be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't return from `if` branches, just assign a value to `a`:

```js
let a = 0
if (a == 0) {a = value0}
else if (a == 1) {a = value1}
else {a = valuex}
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a variable every time inside the condition. So variables will be scoped into brackets not outside of that brackets. So the global variable will not change in your case. And remove return.
Solution is

```
let a = 0
if (a == 0) {
   a = value; 
}
else if (a == 1) {
   a = value1;
}
else {
   a = value;
}
console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the scope of 'a'.
`let` allows us to declare variables that are limited to the scope of a block statement,and once the block closes, it's scope ends.

```
let a = 0
//You don't need to redeclare a by using let
//Also you don't need to return anything since it's not a function
if (a == 0) { a = value0}
else if (a == 1) { a = value1}
else { a = valuex}
console.log(a)
```